# Loading data and singleton for IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, singleton

I am making an instagram clone but I am having abit of question about what would be the best way to pass data arround.

I have 3 post arrays and three VCs as shown below

```
myPosts = [Post]()

nearbyPosts = [Post]()
followingPosts = [Post]()

myPostVC

nearbyPostVC

followingPostVC
```

The interesting part is when I download a post that is close by and it happens to be one of my post that I am also following. So when I download that post, I will need to put it in all three arrays so they are the same reference. This is so that if the user "likes" that post, it will be reflected in all three array because they point to the same post. (If they dont have the same reference, and the user likes or perform any sort of action on a post in myPosts array, I will have to manually loop through each nearbyPosts and followingPosts to update their "like count" individually)

Initially, my code looks this

```
myPost -> Initiated inside myPostVC
nearbyPost -> Initiated inside nearByVC
followingPostVC -> Initiated inside followingPostVC
```

So in myPostVC, I would need to create an instance of nearbyVC and followingPostVC so that everytime I download a post inside myPostVC, I loop through nearbyVC.nearbyPosts and followingPostVC.followingPosts and update anyting that has the same poast as the one that was just downloded. And I do this for all three VC. Imagine if I have moreVC, this gets very messy as each VC is linked to other VC (In my case, the threeVC as three tabs)

This is when I changed to Singleton... I made myPosts, nearbyPosts and followingPosts to be all inside a singleton as shown below. This allows the three VC to be disconnected and they just need to access whichever array they wish to by calling something like PostService.ps.myPosts (Without the need to create a refrence to other VC)

My question is...

1. I know it "might" be good to use the first method because it is not singleton, but is that actually a method people use in this case? (It makes all VC linked together. Very messy)
2. Is singleton the right way to solve this problem or is there a much better way? (Note that similar to instagram, I dont really need to store these posts on the phone to look at in future, so no coredata?)

   ```
   class PostService {


   static let ps = PostService()

   private var _myPosts = [Post]()
   private var _nearbyPosts = [Post]()
   private var _followingPosts = [Post]()

   var myPosts: [Post] {
       return _myPosts

   }

   var nearbyPosts: [Post] {
       return _nearbyPosts
   }

   var followingPosts: [Post] {
       return _followingPosts
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

So many ways to approach this.

Create a new class (such as your `PostService`) to represent your data model, outside of any view controller. This data model class could be a singleton. I would put all of the posts into a single Set (not an array) named `allPosts`. Using a Set rather than an array will prevent any duplicates. Each `Post` object could have boolean vars indicating if it belongs to specific subsets or not. This could be stored or calculated depending on your data.

Then to access a specific subset, use the filter function on the set, such as:

```
var allPosts: Set<Post> = ...

var myPosts: [Post] {
    return allPosts.filter { $0.isMine }
}

var nearbyPosts: [Post] {
    return allPosts.filter { $0.isNearby }
}
```

The advantage here is no duplication of objects and a shared resource for each of your view controllers.

Note: Since this is a Set rather than an Array, it will not have any order to the items it contains. But you can always use the sort() function to do that.

Comment: I like this approach. So do you think singleton is the way to go?

Comment: Yeah, in this case I see no problem with it. Just for convention, I'd use: static let shared = PostService() or static let default = PostService(). It seems more Swifty.